# VSTO Excel Add-in deployment problem using Click Once and Mage

Tags: .net, excel, vsto, clickonce, mage

I have a VSTO Excel add-in that I can publish successfully from within Visual Studio 2008.  I want to move the publishing into a NANT task on my CruiseControl build server so that I get all the benefits of unit testing etc.

I am testing the deployment by building locally and deploying to a share on my machine so I know the commands to use in NANT.

I can successfully build a deployment and application manifest using the Mage commandline tool.

When I run the application from the network share, the installation fails and gives the message:
"**The customHostSpecified attribute is not supported for Windows Forms applications**"

I have looked at various sources for information, most of which suggest using the latest version of the Mage tool (I am using the Mage tool from Windows SDK 7.0a) and making sure that the processor target is MSIL.

I have also followed various MSDN pages and walkthroughs but can't seem to get rid of this problem.

So to summarise:

1. I can deploy via ClickOnce if I publish from Visual Studio 2008
2. I can build the manifests and sign them using the mage cmd tool
3. I cannot install from my network share, I get the "**The customHostSpecified attribute is not supported for Windows Forms applications**" error.
4. I am targeting Excel 2007 and using .NET Framework 3.5.
5. The app is deployed from a network share, not IIS.